# Include modules depending on instant type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have an `Identity` model, which has many `types` (say, `student`, `teacher`). Each of these types has many unique methods defined in different modules, as well as many shared methods.

I would like to include certain modules depending on instant types to avoid naming conflict. Something like:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
 if instant.type =='student'
   include Student
 if instant.type == 'teacher'
   include Teacher
 end
end
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Why not just inherit Student and Teacher classes from Identity?

Comment: I agree with Ivan, unless an entity can be BOTH a teacher and a student, you are better off using STI - http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance

Comment: Thanks Ivan and house9. STI is a sensible option. Unfortunately, I have a large legacy code that will likely to break if convert to STI (As an example, composite key gem I used might break indexing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use after initialize hook to load the correct module.

```
def after_initialize
 if self.type =='student'
   extend Student
 else if self.type == 'teacher'
   extend Teacher
 end
end
```

But you have to make sure that you always initialize your object with a type to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks Vimsha. I tried your solution but it didn't work. Has it been tested?

Comment: Made an edit. Try this. I have used this in one of my project. So i am sure that it should work

Comment: Hi Vimsha, in my case, Student and Teacher are modules and not  classes. I wonder if it will work.

Comment: Thanks Vimsha. The following works: `after_initialize :load_modules ; def load_modules; end;`